# synching problem

Tags: data-synchronization

I'v just upgraded to an iphone 5 after my old 4 died, battery dead and charging mechanism kaput, so not able to transfer data phone to phone.  Tried it on mac at home and it says I need min version 11 on itunes, but when I search for updates it says latest version is 10.6.3 - any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Are you sure you are running OS X 10.6.8 or later? According to http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/ that's what you need to be able to run iTunes 11.

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading v11 from Apple's website:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/

Hope that solves it!